# Como puedo graficar Horas y minutos en report rdl?

Tags: sql, reportviewer, rdlc

Algun ajemplo o link donde pueda ver un ejemplo de como presentar tiempos en una grafica de barras, ya busque en google pero no encuentro algun ejemplo con horas son con enteros u otras cosas pero no con tiempos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui esta el link con informacion que me ayudo a resolver este caso que tenia.
Espero que les ayude en caso de necesitarlo.

Esta en ingles.

[SSRS: Display static time range on y-axis](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bdcda8c0-9140-49e5-9357-7c957b7c349a/solved-ssrs-display-static-time-range-on-yaxis?forum=sqlreportingservices)